# Flex 3: Is It Possible to Use DeepLinking without a ViewStack?

Tags: apache-flex, deep-linking

I've got a Flex 3 project.

Does deep linking only work on viewStacks? (My project doesn't have any viewStacks). I'd like to use deeplinking based on what was selected in a comboBox. I'd like the user to be able to bookmark or use the back button based on what was selected in the comboBox.

The comboBox selection determines which data is pulled from the database.

Is this possible? I set-up deeplinking in another project, but it had viewStacks. And all of the deep linking examples that I've seen use viewStacks.

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the documentation for [BrowserManager](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/BrowserManager.html) and [deep linking.](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=deep_linking_2.html#245307)

You can use Flex deep linking without a component that has it built in, but you need to add the support manually.

You will need to create a `BrowserManager` instance and have it load the URL when your application loads.  You can then use the URL to load the data requested.

You also need to make sure to update the URL using the `BrowserManager` each time your data changes in a way that you want to have a separate link for.

Comment: Hi Alan Geleynse, Thank you for the help.